# Incorporating Jenkins Security in Docker Image?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dockerfile

I am building a custom  docker jenkins image. I thinking to setup jenkins security in image itself. Lets say i want to connect my jenkins instance to AD.
I am thinking how i can achieve this? any help on writing docker file?

--
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to achieve this.

1. Add active directory plugin in docker file and prepare docker image
2. Enable jenkins security realm in jenkins config file
3. Also modify jenkins config with active directory details and mount as volume to the jenkins docker container